# Storm Error when launching multilang subprocess

Tags: java, c++, apache-storm

I have a storm error when i use the cpp wrapper for storm (StormCpp) who use the ShellBolt's multilang subprocess and this one gives me the next error:

> 10784 [Thread-17-split] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error when launching multilang subprocess

This is my Topology Java Code:

```
public class AppCppStorm {
public static class CppStorm extends ShellBolt implements IRichBolt {

    public CppStorm()
    {
        super("test");
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {}

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
        return null;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("spout", new RandomSentenceSpout());

    builder.setBolt("split", new CppStorm())
            .shuffleGrouping("spout");


    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);

    conf.setNumWorkers(3);
    conf.setMaxTaskParallelism(3);

    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology());

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    cluster.shutdown();

}
}
```

If someone can help me in this point, i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the mistake, i did not put in my ShellBolt's Instanciation, the absolute path of my Bolt Cpp Application.